# Как правильно употреблять слово "треснутый"?

Tags: значение-слов, выбор-слов

Задумался о том, правильно ли употребление слова "треснутый", если речь идет о стекле, которое дало трещину? Правильнее ли будет заменить на "треснувший"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Треснутый (разг.) – треснувший.
Большой толковый словарь Кузнецова.

Что делать – так говорят.